# comparing 50,45 to 44,45 in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a field that contains certain ID's comma separated (50,45), and in my select I need to compare that to a array, comma separated (44,45). These value will obviously change query to query, that's just my current data I'm working with.

How can I compare one of the values to the other? So the above query would return the row because either 50 or 45 is in the array 44 and 45.

Comment: you don't. You normalize your table so that the fields with `comma,separated,values` are split off into their own sub-tables, with each value being in a record by itself, and then you can use a plain-jane `JOIN` query to check such things. With your construct, you're in for a massive amount of pain and suffering.

Comment: @MarcB is definitely right, and if that was an answer i'd upvote it straight away. Please take a look here for a read about database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: you can do it in the way provided in the answer but its not a good choice and it affects the performance too. So I will go with @Marc's comment,first you need to normalize your tables. find_in_set may get removed from mysql in upcoming versions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "array", because MySQL does not currently have native support for arrays.

You can do what you want as:

```
where find_in_set(44, '50,45') > 0 or find_in_set(45, '50,45') > 0
```

Comment: BTW when looking for exactly the same values it works in MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24487

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've used a foreach to loop through an build the query using find_in_set OR find_in_set etc.